# What is the working of Browser and Page in QTP/UFT?

Tags: testing, automation, qtp, hp-uft

I always get a doubt that:

What exactly is the difference between the working of Browser and Page.

I know it is a hierarchy and that stuff, but how does the tool differentiates the browser and page and what is use of having both of them.

For example, if I use descriptive programming, and type:

```
Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").something
```

irrespective of the Browser (which may be IE / Chrome / Firefox) it will use the browser with the title = Google. And same is for the page.

Please elaborate. I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an explanation of what `Browser` and `Page` are supposed to represent on [HP's blog](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/Understanding-the-web-test-object-model-in-HP-Unified-Functional/ba-p/6168133).

In short `Page` has no semantic meaning, it is just used in order to organize the object repository more cleanly (so that you don't get hundreds of objects under one `Browser` object). If you're using descriptive programming (as I see from your example) then the `Page` has no meaning (since every browser has only one `Page`) and having a description for the page adds nothing.

I would replace the line with:

```
Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=.*").something
```

Or

```
Browser("title:=Google").Page("micclass:=Page").something
```

Comment: `Browser("title=.*").Page("title:=Google").something` is also same?

I was thinking for this from so long. This is actually useless. Thanks.

Comment: @explorer not exactly, if there are multiple browsers this will fail due to the object not being unique, however if the description is on the `Browser` it will succeed.

Comment: Okay. And I guess it will succeed when there is only one browser.

Thanks for help. I guess you have become my UFT guide! :)